# No such element Exception for Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am doing an assignment for an online course. It's functional programming in Scala. I am working on a function that return a list of pairs with the character in the first index and the number of occurences in the second. I am unfortunately getting an error. My pattern matching case isn't catching cases for an Nil list for some reason. I am getting a No Such Element error. Thank you!

Here is my code

```
  def times(chars: List[Char]): List[(Char, Int)] = {
    // Need to recurse through list
    // Needs to be tail recursive
    def timesAcc(charList: List[Char], acc: List[(Char, Int)]): List[(Char, Int)] = {
      charList match {
        case Nil => acc
        case _ =>
      }

      if(!acc.exists(elem => elem._1 == charList.head)) {
        val count = charList.count(c => c == charList.head)
        timesAcc(charList.tail,(charList.head, count) :: acc)
      }else{
        timesAcc(charList.tail, acc)
      }

    }
    timesAcc(chars, List())
  }
```

Comment: Your parenthesis are mismatched (you are closing the pattern match too early). The pattern match is useless as is. You need to move all the logic to the second `case`

Answer (score 2):

In scala, everything is expression. In your case, it will return value from charList match and execute the code below charList.In scala, we used the recursive function with *@tailrec* annotation to avoid stack overflow problem.

**your code:**

```
val a = charList match {
  case Nil => acc
  case _ =>
}
```

**Solution:**

```
def times(chars: List[Char]): List[(Char, Int)] = {
  // Need to recurse through list
  // Needs to be tail recursive

  @tailrec
  def timesAcc(charList: List[Char], acc: Map[Char, Int]): Map[Char, Int] = {
    charList match {
      case head :: tail => acc.get(head) match {
        case Some(count) => timesAcc(tail, acc ++ Map(head -> (count + 1)))
        case _ => timesAcc(tail, acc ++ Map(head -> 1))
      }

      case _ => acc
    }
  }
  timesAcc(chars, Map.empty).toList
}
```